# How to include first element of selection using nextUntil with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a small button that hides/shows an article on a WordPress implementation food blog.

```
jQuery('.post-entry p').nextUntil('div.tasty-recipes').wrapAll( "<div class='recipe-article recipe-hidden'></div>");

jQuery('#display-recipe-toggle').click(function(){
            jQuery('.recipe-article').toggleClass('recipe-hidden');
})
```

The recipe card is injected, otherwise I would just include it in the template files.

Ideally, I would like my hide/show to include the first paragraph, but does not. I have tried all sorts of variations of

`jQuery('.post-entry').nextUntil('div.tasty-recipes').wrapAll( "<div class='recipe-article recipe-hidden'></div>");`

but the toggle doesn't work (doesn't get wrapped in the div appropriately).

[Here is a page](https://ramshacklepantry.com/sauerkraut-sausage-knoephla/)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your requirement, you want to show 1st paragraph always, and other piece of article toggle on btn click. If so, you can exclude them using jQuery [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) function.

```
jQuery('#display-recipe-toggle').click(function(){
    jQuery('.recipe-article').children().not('ul, h2:first, p:first').toggle();
})
```

Also, I'd advise you to use jQuery native [toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method instead of toggleClass. It makes no sense to toggle class with only property `display:none;` when native method is provided to do the same work.

Comment: no, sorry if I explained incorrectly. I want the first paragraph to be included. Currently, it excludes the first paragraph with the em tag as the child.